# Getting nth parameter type from ConstructorParameters

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use the `ConstructorParameters` type to get the first arguments type of a class constructor as an extension for an interface (probably better to show code):

```
// base.ts ---------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IConfig {
  someProperty: string;
}

export class Base {
  constructor(config: IConfig) {
  }
}

// derived.ts ------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IConfig extends ConstructorParameters<typeof Base> {
                                                         // ^ tried [0] here but 
                                                         // that doesn't work
}

export class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(config: IConfig) {
    super(config); // this doesn't work because ConstructorParameters returns
                   // a type tuple which is then placed on IConfig for this
                   // class.  I want to pick the type of the first argument
                   // and I can't figure out how to select just the first
                   // arguments type (i.e. [0] but that doesn't work).
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work please or know something I don't for using the `ConstructorParameters` type?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out (open to other suggestions though):

```
// derived.ts ------------------------------------------------------------------
type BaseConfigType = ConstructorParameters<typeof Base>[0];
interface IConfig extends BaseConfigType {

}

export class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(config: IConfig) {
    super(config); // this now works :)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the way to do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of inheritance to provide extensibility *(in the way of the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle))*. Still, in this situation, I would rather design the base class so that it is explicitly extensible and on what, here on its configuration input parameter, using a generic type constraint and exporting the base configuration type.

```
// base.ts ---------------------------------------------------------------------
export interface IBaseConfig {
  someProperty: string;
}

export class Base<TConfig extends IBaseConfig = IBaseConfig> {
  constructor(config: TConfig) {
  }
}

// derived.ts ------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IDerivedConfig extends IBaseConfig {
  otherProperty: string;
}

export class Derived extends Base<IDerivedConfig> {
  constructor(config: IDerivedConfig) {
    super(config);
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

When the "base" class is not in our hand, extra care is needed :

1. Unless the "base" class is designed to be extended by inheritance, don't inherit from this class, use composition with [forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming)). That way, we protect ourselve from hard to find bugs like [Fragile Base Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). More info: see [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).
2. Protect the client of our class from change in the "base" class. Master every types that are exposed and hide other types, for instance by wrapping the type from `base.ts`.

This is one option to do it:

```
// base.ts ---------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IConfig {
  someProperty: string;
}

export class Base {
  constructor(config: IConfig) { }
  compute(arg: any): string { return 'any-string'; }
  do(): void {}
}

// derived.ts ------------------------------------------------------------------
export interface IDerivedConfig { /* TBD */ }

export class Derived {
  static create(config: IDerivedConfig): Derived {
    const baseConfig = {} as any /* TODO: replace `{} as any` with the custom mapping from `config` to a base config object. */;
    const base = new Base(baseConfig);
    return new Derived(base);
  }

  private constructor(
    private readonly base: Base,
  ) { }

  compute(arg: any) {
    return this.base.compute(arg);
  }

  do() {
    this.base.do();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `IDerivedConfig` does not extends "`IConfig`" *(that we get with your tip: `type BaseConfigType = ConstructorParameters<typeof Base>[0]`)* in order to be fully in our hand and prevent change in the base config to propagate to all construction sites in our clients.
- `Derived` class `implements Base` (instead of `extends Base`). Still, it's not necessary to code it but in the beginning to be sure of the type compatibility. Then removing it is safer. If the base class changes, we can choose to propagate the change or just code our class as an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).
- `Derived` class has a static factory method to create it, function that call the private constructor that defines inline the private readonly "base" object.
- In `Derived.create()` method, `baseConfig` is typed implicitly, by inference. The code is safe because the compiler prevents us from passing incompatible arguments to the `Base` constructor.

Comment: I agree completely, but this is assuming that you can change the base.ts class and interface definitions.

Comment: @Anupheaus: I have added an "Edit" section with another option when we can not change `base.ts`.